# find out if string starts with "vybe" followed by numbers in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to know how to find out if a string starts with "vybe" followed by numbers..like this : "vybe1232", in javascript. Would this be done using regex?

Comment: yes. something like /^vybe[0-9]{4}/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
var str = "vybe1234";
var re = /^vybe\d+$/
console.log( re.test(str) );
```

- `^` start of a string
- `vybe` match the characters
- `\d+` match one or more digits
- `$` end of string

Comment: I'd remove the end-of-string, op didn't actually specify that.  Good answer though.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use a regexp, with [`String.match()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match):

```
if (myString.match(/^vybe\d+/)) {
    // it matches!
}
```

Your question was slightly ambiguous about the *ending* of the string - if you want it to *only* contain the prefix and digits, put a `$` before the final `/` character:

```
if (myString.match(/^vybe\d+$/)) {
    // it matches!
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a simple regular expression:

```
 var str1 = 'vybe1234', 
     str2='other111', 
     re=/^vybe[0-9]+/;

 alert( str1.match(re) ); // shows "vybe1234" match
 alert( str2.match(re) ); // shows "null" no match
```